# How to have the browser link generated automatically to view the email in a browser?

Tags: email, email-template

As of now, every time I make an email template in Salesforce, I need to manually make a browser url link to view the email also in a browser. Is it possible in Salesforce to somehow have the browser links of the emails automatically generated? What should I look into.

Comment: Please post the steps you are following when creating the email template. That way, contributors can offer better suggestions.

Comment: I am not creating the email template, so unsure about that, but so far, I am going into the HTML code and directly editing the anchor tag and adding the url link so far. Is there a way to generate the browser link every time when making the email template? @GroundToCloud